# Flask-SQLAlchemy query not querying as per the request

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have a flask environment with SQLLite, I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy to query the tables and output to a template file. I have a Users table and a settings_company table and would like to query the chatai_conversation associated with the logged in user. Ie. the query I am trying to execute is

```
`select chatai_conversation from Users left JOIN settings_company on Users.companyid = settings_company.companyid where users.companyid=1`
```

Users table

[image: Users Database]

settings_company table
[image: settings_company Database]

My model for the SettingsCompany is as follows:

```
def get_chataitconversation(user_id):
    user_settings = SettingsCompany.query.filter_by(companyid=user_id).first()
    if user_settings:
        return user_settings.chatai_conversation
    else:
        return None  # or return a default value or raise an exception
```

My route is as follows:

```
@blueprint.route('/page-profile/')
def display_chatai():
    user_id = 1
    aisetting = get_chataitconversation(user_id)
    return render_template('/home/page-profile.html',  aisetting = aisetting)
```

In my template file , I add the {{aisetting}}

I keep getting a return of NONE - which means its not querying the data correctly?

Comment: So ive changed it to " user_settings = SettingsCompany.query.filter_by(SettingsCompany.companyid1==user_id).first()" - now I get the error "TypeError: Query.filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: FYI "SettingsCompany.query.filter_by(companyid==user_id).first()" - it wont accept the companyid , it only allows SettingsCompany.companyid

Comment: Sorry, `Filter_by` is different to `filter`.

Comment: So, then it should be what? I have used Filter and Filter_by, both give errors using your suggestion

Comment: Only other suggestion is to do `print(SettingsCompany.query.filter_by(companyid=user_id))` and check that the SQL is what you expect.

Comment: So I get this "SELECT settings_company.id AS settings_company_id, settings_company.companyname AS settings_company_companyname, settings_company.companyid1 AS settings_company_companyid1, settings_company.chatai_conversation AS settings_company_chatai_conversation FROM settings_company WHERE settings_company.companyid1 = ?"    Notice the ? probably means its not accepting the user_id, but why?